# R: how do I allocate a big vector

Tags: r

I am currently using aws ec2 to run my r program. I have a fairly big machine (g3.4xlarge   16  47  122 GiB memory).

I installed R studio and my data set is about 2 million rows. (~ 1.5 GB ish)

I broke down my data set as below:

```
intrain<- createDataPartition(overall_data$churn,p=0.7,list=FALSE)
set.seed(2017)
training<- overall_data[intrain,]
testing<- overall_data[-intrain,]
```

I then applied the below code to my test data. My test data is about 600 k rows. So its pretty small imo.

```
testing = sapply(testing, function(col) length(unique(col)))
testing=Filter(function(col)(length(unique(col))>1), testing)
testing = subset(testing, select = -c(payer_account_id))
testing[sapply(testing, is.character)] <- lapply(testing[sapply(testing, is.character)],as.factor)
```

However, when i run my program

```
LogModel <- glm(churn ~ .,family=binomial(link="logit"),data=testing)
```

It tells me that

```
> LogModel <- glm(churn ~ .,family=binomial(link="logit"),data=testing)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 250.3 Gb
```

I tried even with a bigger ec2 instance but this failed also. I tried on my windows laptop and this is what i did

```
> memory.limit(size=1800)
[1] 16222
Warning message:
In memory.limit(size = 1800) : cannot decrease memory limit: ignored
> memory.limit()
[1] 16222
> memory.limit(size = 56000)
[1] 56000
> LogModel <- glm(churn ~ .,family=binomial(link="logit"),data=testing)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 250.1 Gb
```

As such, im quite puzzled why R is not able to process such a small data set. I referred to the other stackoverflow guides but nthing seems to work.

Can i ask if anyone resolved this?

Comment: I suspect you have a huge design matrix due to the dummy encoding of factors with many levels.

Comment: Maybe package biglm can help.

Comment: Thank you roland. I tried to do LogModel <- bigglm(formula= churn ~ .,data=testing, family=binomial(link="logit"),chunksize=100, maxit=10) but its giving me a Error in terms.formula(formula) : '.' in formula and no 'data' argument. any advice?